# How to disable build caching with angular 17

Tags: angular, stenciljs

I noticed in my Chrome DevTools `Network` tab that all files come from

http://localhost:4200/@fs/Users/lucas/tmp/pux/xyz/.angular/cache/17.0.6/vite/deps/....

This `.angular/cache` forlder probably holds all files and the build does caching.
In my case however, I'm also working in one of my node_modules dependencies (stenciljs project). I need to debug it. The problem now is, is that the angular build caches all those files, meaning that when I make a change in my node_modules/stencil Project I also have to remove that `.angular` folder.

So my question is, is there a way to just disable cache at all?

Comment: https://angular.io/cli/cache `ng cache disable`